# Changing Proxy Port in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, proxy, firefox-extensions

I often find myself going to Firefox > Options > General > Network Proxy > Settings > Manual Proxy Configuration and setting the port.

**Option 1:** Is there a way to increase the port number by one everytime I open Firefox. Eg: If the port is 2000, it becomes 2001 and so on.

**Option 2:** If option 1 addon or method does not exist, is there a way I can specify a list of proxy and ports that the addon can automatically pick up from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SwitchyOmega](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchyomega/) Firefox's extension where you can set up multiple proxies (including SOCKS) and choose them on demand from extension's icon.
Anything that you can setup in firefox can be set in SwitchyOmega

P.S. Extension supposed to work in new (Quantum and above) firefox's versions.
If you still use pre-quantum version of firefox then look for addons ProxySwitcher that doing the same things.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. Can I create a shortcut to directly reach Proxy Config in Firefox? The maximum I have gone is to about:configuration

Comment: No, not without writing your own extension, plus it pretty annoying to do it manually every time you need to change something. In SwitchyOmega it is just a matter of a two clicks to choose profile you need

Comment: No problem, Im glad you like it

Comment: I took your advice and have started using SwitchyOmega. Is there a way I can specify a range of ports for eg: 8000 to 10000 and then use the 'auto switch' feature of switchy to rotate these ports in a random order?

Comment: @CuriousDev  Interesting feature, never tried that. You better ask this question on author's [github issues tracker](https://github.com/FelisCatus/SwitchyOmega/issues). Author is very responsive and willing to help/improve that plugin.